# SharePoint 2010: Programmatic changes to user property not creating change token

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I have a webpart that provides an interface to a new field for users, and when I save the changes, I notice that there arent any new events in the collection returned from the profile.GetChanges() method.

Here is the way I am setting the property:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                UserProfileManager manager = new UserProfileManager(context);

                UserProfile profile = manager.GetUserProfile(recordId);
                profile["SPS-School"].Value = serializedData;
                profile.Commit();
            }
```

The data is being saved, I know that but the change is not being recorded. Am I doing it a different way, or is there a way to force a change token to be created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by checking the "Show updates to the property in newsfeed" attribute on the property in question. That may be all that is needed to get it into the change log. It may also be how are you querying for changes. I wrote an article about this with Gary a while back: http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/monitor-sharepoint-user-profile-changes

Matt